# Running Groovy in Email Extension Plugin Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-email-ext

I need to create a url and send a mail from the Jenkins Email Plugin. I simply need the filenames to creat the url. The files are in the workspace itself. After searching around I found that only `groovy` script can be used in the email body.

My attempt was this, I created a folder called `email-template` in the Jenkins folder where it looks for email template. [Ref](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/#plugin-content-groovy-script-content-templates) . In the email body, I called it like this

`${SCRIPT, template="email.groovy"}`

This is the script

```
import groovy.io.FileType

File folder = new File('C://Tosca_Projects//OneDrive//ToscaPDFLogs')

folder.eachFileRecurse FileType.FILES,  { file ->

    
    if (!file.name.endsWith(".pdf")) {
        println "Processing file ${file.absolutePath}"
    }
}
```

This gives me an error

> Exception raised during template rendering: No such property: file for
> class: SimpleTemplateScript13

*Info*:- When I run a build step 'run groovy script' ..it works fine. One other hint is..when I change the code to any other `groovy` code..it starts printing the code itself. For e.g
`import groovy.io.FileType new File('C://Tosca_Projects//OneDrive//ToscaPDFLogs').traverse(type: groovy.io.FileType.FILES) { it -> println it }`

It will send the script text in the email.

Comment: Your Groovy syntax is inccroect, try `folder.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) { file -> ...`

Comment: Are you running a pipeline job? if so why do you need the template?

Comment: @NoamHelmer https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/#plugin-content-groovy-script-content-templates

Answer (score 0):

I have the following example may help you to get the file name

```html
import groovy.io.FileType

def list = []

def dir = new File("/home/multi_files/files")
dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
  list << file.getName()
}

list.each {
  println it
}
```

result
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
Result: [1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt]