# Creating custom groovy template for email-ext plugin

Tags: templates, jenkins, groovy, email-ext

I am trying to send files of XML and pdf formats using Jenkins emailext plugin running pipeline. I don't have much idea on groovy script. Hence, following the given reference
[Running Groovy in Email Extension Plugin Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72138205/running-groovy-in-email-extension-plugin-jenkins) I customised my code and used similar script. Still ended with:
"Exception raised while parsing the groovy template error"
Error similar to the error in shared reference.
If anyone have any idea on writing custom .groovy template for email-ext plugin, please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to send files as attachments?

Comment: Yes. Though I used attachmentsPattern parameter, other than default type files [html/text] I can't able to attach other type of docs. Even if I try, it doesn't throws any error but an empty mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach any file using `attachmentsPattern`. The file has to reside in the workspace for this to work. So I'm suspecting you may be having an issue with your pattern.

```
emailext attachmentsPattern: '**/report.pdf', body: 'Find attachments', subject: 'test', to: 'test@me.org'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Issue is with my body step. I used it as ${SCRIPT, template=...} that just allowed default types Maybe I thought of it in a complex way. It worked well but single report got sent 2 times. Not a big deal but thankyou so much 